# Imaginary folder when I use "DirectoryIterator" in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to count the number of the files in different folders using PHP. The folder's names are numbers starting from 1 to 26.
I have used the iterator_count() PHP function to do that. This is what I have written:

```
$noCoords = array();
for ($number = 1; $number <= 26; $number++) {
     $x = iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator('/Images/'.$number.'/file'));
     $noCoords[$number] = $x-2; // removing . and .. files
     array_push($noCoords,$x);
}

$noCoords=json_encode($noCoords);
echo($noCoords);
```

In my web app I use javascript to alert the json returned:

```
var noCoordsImages = function(){    
        $.get('requestsII/count_noCoords_images.php', function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
```

And here I get the problem. Instead of getting an alert box with a json with 26 outputs (one for each folder), I get 27. It even assigns a value to the 27th folder. In my directory there is no folder with the name: "27".
Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Your `array_push()` always adds one extra record on top of what you are accessing via the key, guess it's a line you forgot to remove when you added the `$x-2` variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me phrase this as an answer:

For every iteration you are actually adding an extra record to the array because of the `array_push()`

With `$noCoords[$number] = $x-2` you'll add index 1 through 26 and the line after you create an extra entry with `$number + 1`

So what happens (assume your folder 25 and 26 have 100 and 90 files respectively):

$index = 25:

```
$noCoords[25] = 98; // $noCoords[$number] = $x-2
$noCoords[26] = 100; // array_push($noCoords,$x);
```

$index = 26:

```
$noCoords[26] = 88; // $noCoords[$number] = $x-2
$noCoords[27] = 90; // array_push($noCoords,$x);
```